# How to pass null as value for maxLength for intercomponent communication in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

```
<input type="text" #input *ngIf="!multiLine" [set-focus]="autoFocus" autocomplete="off" [value]="defaultValue" (input)="onChange()" [placeholder]="placeholder" [maxLength]="maxLen == true ? 250 : null"/>
```

this is my code but when i call it from another component and  inspect  maxLength is 0

```
<input _ngcontent-ueu-c888="" type="text" autocomplete="off" ng-reflect-set-focus="false" placeholder="Domain" maxlength="0" class="ng-star-inserted">
```

[image: how it is displayed in inspect element]

how to pass null value or remove the functionality maxlength attribute when maxLen == false

Comment: Bind the maxlength with some variable in the component, and assign whatever you want.

Comment: Its [maxlength] not [maxLength].

Comment: Are your sure that your variable "maxLen" is not null and initialized? Can you share more code here for reference?

Comment: Instead of null you could set it to the default html max length value which is 524288 or any number you like. This will result 250 if the maxLen is true and the default value 524288 if the maxLen is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using property binding, make use of attribute binding as below:

```html
[attr.maxlength]="maxLen ? 250 : null"
```

Comment: doesn't this have an effect on the angular form validation?